# How to deal with this warning at 15 and 18."warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]"

Tags: c, hash

the problem is this warning at 15 and 18
 warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]

deal with
Sample Input:
They are students.
aeiou
Sample Output:
Thy r stdnts.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
const int MAXN = 10005;
char str1[MAXN], str2[MAXN];
bool HashTable[128] = {false};
//use HashTable to record the item need to minus

int main()
{
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        HashTable[str2[i]] = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        if (HashTable[str1[i]] == false) {
            printf("%c", str1[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can run it, but the warning  I have no idea.

here

Comment: Maybe the compile fears the char can be negative... Try with unsigned chars

Comment: It seems to me the warning is not useful here since even a signed `char` can cover the index range of the array.

Comment: There is an independent problem, however. `str1[i]` and `str2[i]` could be outside of the bounds of `HashTable`.

Comment: The warnings are a bit aggressive.  If you're confident your code is correct and just want to bypass the warnings, you can use `HashTable[(int)str2[i]]` and `HashTable[(int)str1[i]]`.

Comment: From GCC documentation: _"This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines."_

Comment: If somebody enters an emoji character, your program has an out-of-bounds array index.

Comment: casting char to int should suppress the warning `HashTable[(int)str2[i]] = true;`

Comment: Your code is C++ not C, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the `char` to `int` or promoting it, e.g., with the unary plus would rid you of the warning.

Note that if the user can enter anything they want (and they usually can)
you're risking an out-of-bound access as you could get either a value larger than `127` if `char` is unsigned or a negative value if `char` is signed.

The safest strategy would be to expand the array to size `256` and cast the char to `unsigned char` before using it as an index.